# Автогенерация комментариев в Eclipse for Java EE

Tags: eclipse, java, комментарии

Подскажите, как можно автоматически генерировать и подставлять комментарии в Eclipse.

Интересует следующее: необходимо подставлять в самом начале класса/файла определённый комментарий с именем автора и датой последнего изменения. Понимаю, что копать надо в Window->Preferences->Java и Project->Properties, а вот дальше у меня возникли трудности...

UPD: Нашёл плагин http://jautodoc.sourceforge.net/. Вроде в нём есть необходимый мне функционал.

Comment: как вариант вы можете создать для билда ant файл и заменять properties при коппировании значениями заданными из файла при билде. или сделать на том же анте скрипт для чекина с предыдущей заменой текущей даты и версии

Answer (score 1):

*Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates*, есть настройки глобальные и для каждого проекта в отдельности.

Comment: Я понимаю, а можешь ли подсказать как именно дату последнего изменения включить, чтобы она автоматически подставлялась при сохранении?

Comment: Ага, такого не знаю. Видимо, тот плагин как раз и есть ваше решение.